# FileStream.Read() - bytes read

Tags: c#, .net

`FileStream.Read()` returns the amount of bytes read, but... is there any situation other than having reached the end of file, that it will read less bytes than the number of bytes requested **and not throw an exception**?

the documentation says:

> The Read method returns zero only after reaching the end of the stream. Otherwise, Read always reads at least one byte from the stream before returning. If no data is available from the stream upon a call to Read, the method will block until at least one byte of data can be returned. An implementation is free to return fewer bytes than requested even if the end of the stream has not been reached.

But this doesn't quite explain in what situations data would be unavailable and cause the method to block until it can read again. I mean, shouldn't most situations where data is unavailable force an exception?

What are real situations where comparing the number of bytes read against the number of expected bytes could differ (assuming that we're already checking for end of file when we mention number of bytes expected)?

**EDIT:** A bit more information, reason why I'm asking this is because I've come across a bit of code where the developer pretty much did something like this:

```
bytesExpected = (remainingBytesInFile > 94208 ? 94208 : remainingBytesInFile
while (bytesRead < bytesExpected)
{
      bytesRead += fileStream.Read(buffer, bytesRead, bytesExpected - bytesRead)
}
```

Now, I can't see any advantage to having this while at all, I'd expect it to throw an exception if it can't read the number of bytes expected (bearing in mind it's already taking into account that there are those many bytes left to read)

What would the reason one could possibly have for something like this? I'm sure I'm missing something

Comment: It says an implementation, but does that particular one do that? Plus dont you just compare sha hashes to check for integrity and throw then!

Comment: If it cannot read any bytes because of some I/O issue, it would throw an `IOException` as the docs say. What is your actual problem? What's the problem you are facing?

Comment: Yeah, to be honest I don't see any problem with that statement. You request as much as you want, it gives you as much as possible. Then you just integrity check at the end. So you can have two exceptions thrown, `IOException` then your own `IntegrityException`

Comment: One case where fewer bytes are read is a network stream: some bytes are buffered, but fewer than requested. The read returns with the buffered bytes rather than blocking indefinitely waiting for more from the remote end.

Comment: Look at the reference source for [FileStream.Read](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,f54c954df34d7a92). It eventually calls [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx), which *can* return a short block. In particular, if the `FileStream` is wrapping a pipe handle. It doesn't look like it'll return a short block in other cases, but that's just an implementation detail. I would recommend that you write your code with the assumption that short blocks are possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation is for `Stream.Read`, from which `FileStream` is derived. Since `FileStream` is a stream, it should obey the stream contract. Not all streams do, but unless you have a very good reason, you should stick to that.

In a typical file stream, you'll only get a return value smaller than count when you reach the end of file (and it's a pretty simple way of checking for the end of file).

However, in a `NetworkStream`, for example, you keep reading in a loop until the method returns zero - signalling the end of stream. The same works for file streams - you know you're at the end of the file when `Read` returns zero.

Most importantly, `FileStream` isn't just for what you'd consider files - it's also for pseudo-files like standard input/output pipes and COM ports, for example (try opening a file stream on `PRN`, for example). In that case, you're not reading a file with a fixed length, and the behaviour is the same as with `NetworkStream`.

Finally, don't forget that `FileStream` isn't sealed. It's perfectly fine for you to implement a virtualized file system, for example - and it's perfectly fine if your virtualized file system doesn't support seeking, or checking the length of file.

**EDIT:**

To address your edit, this is exactly how you're supposed to read any stream. Nothing wrong with it. If there's nothing else to read in  a stream, the `Read` method will simply return `0`, and you know the stream is over. The only thing is, it seems that he tries to fill his buffer to full, one buffer at a time - this only makes sense if you explicitly need to partition the file by 94208 bytes, and pass that `byte[]` for further processing somewhere.

If that's not the case, you don't really need to fill the full buffer - you just keep reading (and probably writing on some other side) until `Read` returns `0`. And indeed, by default, `FileStream` will always fill the whole buffer *unless* it's built around a pipe handle - but since that's a possibility, you shouldn't rely on the "real file" behaviour, so as long as you need those `byte[]` for something non-stream (e.g. parsing messages), this is entirely fine. If you're only using the stream as an actual stream, and you're streaming the data somewhere else, it doesn't have a point, really - you only need one `while` to read the file.

Comment: Luaan, I think you misunderstood what he's doing there. I left out the outer while. Basically he knows exactly how many bytes there are left in the `FileStream` and he requests exactly that number. Then he loops until he's guaranteed that he read the number of bytes he was expecting to read.

Comment: Here's an example: Let's say your buffer is 2048 bytes, you have 10000 bytes left on the stream, so he requests 2048 bytes. Until `Read()` returns the expected 2048 bytes, he just keeps looping and asking for the remaining bytes (i.e, 2048 - bytesAlreadyRead), until he has the full 2048 he expected. Then obviously not shown on the code above is the bit where he does something with those bytes and goes back for another 2048 bytes (or whatever is left on the stream if lower than 2048 bytes in this example). But why 2 whiles?

Comment: @JohnUbuntu In that case, I haven't misunderstood - that's exactly what I tried to describe in my edit. Perhaps something about it is unclear? The main question is, what happens with the `byte[2048]`? If there's something that requires chunks of 2048 bytes, explicitly - it's a perfectly fine approach. If he just treats it as data in a stream, however (e.g. just doing `Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)`), it's completely unnecessary.

Comment: the `byte[2048]` is base64 encoded before being sent over, so that's the reason why he requires exactly those number of bytes, but there are other ways of doing this... creating a new `byte[readBytes]` from the `byte[2048]` which gets encoded into base64 for example... I sort of see the loop on the read as more costly.

Comment: @JohnUbuntu Costly? That's one thing you don't need to care about at all. The CPU work being done is absolutely trivial compared to the I/O work. The I/O work is *exactly* the same, no matter the approach (remember, you're working with buffered data anyway). This is exactly the kind of usecase where this approach is a great idea. Creating a new byte array for "smaller" data returned would be far more costly. If you don't understand this, intuitively, you really need to study a bit what's happening on each of the levels - why we use pre-allocated buffers in the first place etc.

Comment: @JohnUbuntu But to present just a tiny fragment: you need to realize that the buffer you pass to `Read` is used in a native, unmanaged call. Unmanaged code has no idea about references, it only deals with pointers, so the managed memory must be *pinned* in place - it cannot move, because there's no way to tell the unmanaged code the move happened. If you just create a new `byte[]` and pass it to `Read`, it means that the managed heap cannot be compacted until `Read` returns - new allocations are always on top of the heap, so when you pin it, you increase your risk of heap fragmentation.

Comment: @JohnUbuntu Another point is that there's certain fixed overhead with Base-64 encoding - it's more effective to encode bigger pieces at a time. If  your input file is standard input, for example, you could end up sending e.g. individual lines (or even characters) of text, one after another. This can potentially increase your overhead by quite a bit - in the worst case, it's actually easy to send more overhead than real information. Base-64 is designed for messages, not streams. By explicitly partitioning the input stream into distinct messages, the author makes a better use of Base-64.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87978/discussion-between-johnubuntu-and-luaan).

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations would only apply to the case when the stream is reading data off of a no-latency source. Other I/O sources can be slow, which is why the `Read` method might will not always be able to return immediately. That doesn't mean that there is an error (so no exception), just that it has to wait for data to arrive.

Examples: network stream, file stream on slow disk, etc.

**(UPDATE, HDD example)** To give an example specific to files (since your case is `FileStream`, although `Read` is defined on `Stream` and so all implementations should fulfill the requirements): mechanical hard-drives go to "sleep" when not active (specially on battery-powered devices, read laptops). Spinning up can take a second or so. That is not an `IOException`, but your read would have to wait for a second before any data is read.

Comment: Sure, but then the method would not return anything until it's finished. And by the time it finishes and returns something, the number of bytes read should match the expected bytes to read

Comment: @JohnUbuntu: No, that is not how it works. There really is no "expected number of bytes", you only specify the size of your buffer. It specifically says that it is the MAXIMUM number of bytes it is allowed to read, not the MINIMUM or EXPECTED. You send a buffer to the read method and you specify the length of your buffer (maximum number of bytes to read). The read method will tell you how many bytes it wrote to your buffer in the return value. The number of bytes it actually manages to read in one call depends on the type of stream, and specific situation.

Comment: You're missing my point. You gave an example of mechanical HDDs going to sleep when not active. That would only mean that the Read() method takes longer to finish, it would halt execution until the drive was in a ready state, perform the read, and then return the number of bytes read - regardless of how many that was. A drive that's "sleeping" would have no affect in bytes read.

Comment: @JohnUbuntu: you can not assume that, it is not guaranteed by the specification. That may be the case most of the time, but it is not guaranteed. For all you know, the I/O API of the OS might only deliver 64K at a time (just an example). The point is that you can not assume things which are not in the specification.

Comment: The amount it delivers is irrelevant, the point is the Read() method will not complete until it's read something. From doumentation: If no data is available from the stream upon a call to Read, **the method will block** until at least one byte of data can be returned.

Comment: @JohnUbuntu: yes, but that has already been established. You wrote above: "And by the time it finishes and returns something, the number of bytes read should match the expected bytes to read", which is incorrect. Reading something doesn't necessarily have to be everything, you could get a single byte as the specification states.

Comment: what I meant by **should match** was assuming everything goes well (hence the should). Of course it can't be guaranteed, but that was the whole point of this question to begin with: in what situations is that not the case. Regardless, my point is that your example about a HDD that's gone to sleep would not cause `Read()` to return less bytes just because the device is sleeping. It would cause it to take longer to return anything at all, because it needs to wait for the device to wake up, but it would not impact the amount of bytes returned.

Comment: Your whole answer was about latency, which can exist of course, but just means that the method takes longer to complete, but has no affect at all in the amount of bytes returned. The original question was in which situations could the amount of bytes returned differ from the amount of bytes expected excluding when end of stream is reached.

Comment: @JohnUbuntu You wrote: "But this doesn't quite explain in what situations data would be unavailable and cause the method to block until it can read again. I mean, shouldn't most situations where data is unavailable force an exception?" in your original question. It is an answer to that question.

Comment: Point taken, but that's only part of the question, the main part is in which situations would it return less bytes than expected (assuming we're already accounting for end of stream)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that on a FileStream it probably never happens. 
However keep in mind that the Read method is inherited from Stream which serves as base for many other streams like NetworkStream and in this case you may not be able to read has many bytes as you requested simple because they havent been received from the network yet.

So like the documentation says it all depends on the implementation of the specific type of stream - FileStream, NetworkStream, etc.